# Serial port communication using WCF?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Are there any bindings to communicate on Serial port using WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing more about what you're up to, but probably easiest to take it down a layer. If you're just talking about two machines where you control both sides, set up a Dialup Networking PPP connection between the machines over a null modem and use WCF with standard HTTP or NetTcp over the pipe.

Answer (score 3):

OK I couldn't find any workable solution. Thus started to build a custom channel.

http://wcfserialchannels.codeplex.com

Interested developers please join.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know how to do it ,but here is a [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/NullTransportForWCF.aspx) article on how to make your own transport for WCF. You could make one for to use a serial port. I am not familiar with WCF so i dont know if this article can help you, but it looks promising.